# Ford Ka 1.3 2012 over-revving when driving along

Tags: ka

When I am driving along my car starts over-revving up to 4000 RPM randomly.  I've carried out a slippage test and there is no clutch slippage. Any ideas guys?

Comment: How often does this happen @mikepont, and how long does it last? If you keep the car in neutral does the same thing occur?

Comment: It varies,some times just once or twice on a drive of say 20 miles. Other times three or four times within 10 miles.

Comment: It never happens in neutral, and its back to normal after I release the accelerator for a second.

Comment: Does the car accelerate when it revs, or stay at a constant speed?

Comment: It stays at a constant speed, the rev counter just races up to 4 or 5 thousand revs.Normally when I'm going over 60.

Comment: Do you think it could be the clutch on way out after all ?

Comment: If the vehicle does not change speed when this happens and the clutch is not slipping then you should consider a gauge fault...

Answer (score 1):

Frustrating! If it's happening intermittently then there's a few things it could be:

**Oil leaking into the clutch casing**

This could be coming from various places - but if you get any oil on the friction plate you'll get temporary slip from the clutch until it burns off.

**Bad flywheel**

Possible.. but I think you'd be seeing more consistent symptoms then you are.

**Misaligned/sticking clutch bearing**

If you're seeing the symptoms happen *after* you've changed gear then the clutch bearing could be at fault - if it's not doing it's job properly the friction plate might not be settling back in contact properly. Have a listen to see if you can hear any growling or rattling sounds coming from the transmission when the symptoms occur.

**Clutch linkage**

Again this would only be happening when you change gears, and you'd usually feel some vibration or sticking when moving the pedal.

**Broken friction plate springs**

This is *incredibly* rare - but it does cause symptoms remarkably like what you describe:

[image: Broken clutch plate springs]

Basically when the bits of spring come away they get trapped against the friction material and cause it to intermittently drag.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response, I'll have to do a bit more investigating before taking on the clutch change. cheers.